how are Cloudwatch logs and metrics collected from an aws lambda?
I want to understand the performance implications.  e.g., or is there a remote call for each logline? or is there an in-memory or file buffer for periodic push?

The AWS Lambda service sends metrics to CloudWatch Metrics and logs to CloudWatch Logs.
There is no "performance implication" on your actual Lambda function -- it is done in the backend of the Lambda service.

Thanks @john; there should be some performance impact even if very little. I.e. if the logs and metrics are buffered in memory then possibly one network call every minute or so? Otherwise, if there is a network call for each log or put-metric invocation, then that seems very inefficient to me as some applications are quite metric heavy.
Basically, i want to ascertain if i should write some buffering before invoking PutMetric or is that already taken care of by the underlying utility/aws libraries.
